# routes.rb on Spree

Tags: spree

I wanted to be able to default the root to the login page. I have this entry in routes.rb:

```
root :to => "users#show"
```

However after login, the user is redirected to the My Account page. I want it to go to the product selection page. As a rails newbie, I am lost on where to look and change the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be a solution for your is to create a user_sessions_decorator.rb inside your app/controllers directory and [add this](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/spree-user@googlegroups.com/2011-03/msg00386.html). Give me feedback if it not work.

Answer (score 0):

Correct solution will be to create a decorator for session controller and redirect according to your need or user account page

Answer (score 0):

You can use spree_current_user method in your controllers and redirect accordingly...